# Mark a function as "Does not return" in .NET

Tags: .net, exception

I have a method in VB.NET which is just a helper for throwing
exceptions. It will always throw an exception and never returns
However the compiler does not detect this function as a terminating
code path and thus I get warning if I use 
variables later on in the code that are not initialized via the exception code path.

```
Function Foo(y as Integer) As Boolean
    dim x as boolean
    if y > 10
        x = 20
    else
        ThrowHelperFunction("Ouch")
    end if
    return x
End Function
```

The warning is that x is not initialized on all code paths.

Comment: Of course I can just create a special exception class and directly throw in the else clause but that is not the question.

Comment: I assume your question is also not about how you can assign `20` to a `boolean` :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

There is a way since .NET Standard 2.1 (.NET 5 and newer):

```cs
[DoesNotReturn]
private void FailFast()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

Or conditionally:

```cs
private void FailFastIf([DoesNotReturnIf(true)] bool isNull)
{
    if (isNull)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.doesnotreturnattribute?view=net-8.0

**Original answer:**

I don't think that you can change that behavior. Instead you can do something like:

```
Function Foo(y as Integer) As Boolean
    dim x as boolean
    if y > 10
        x = 20
    else
        throw CreateExceptionHelperFunction("Ouch")
    end if
    return x
End Function
```

That is, the helper function can still do some processing. But it will return an exception instead of throwing it.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it was obvious :(

Comment: Well, it *is* obvious when you look into it or attempt it yourself, I was just adding the missing info for the passers-by.

Comment: Yeah that this the pretty obvious solution is to use an exception factory pattern rather than throwing deep. I just remember from gcc that there is a way to mark a function as no return for just this purpose in C/C++. I thought that perhaps .NET might have some pragma to help in this area as well.

Comment: DoesNotReturnAttribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.doesnotreturnattribute

Answer (score 1):

try to initialize x with some default value like this. Boolean is Value Type and should never initialize with null value.

```
Function Foo(y as Integer) As Boolean     
    dim x as boolean     
    x = 0
    if y > 10         
        x = 20     
    else         
        throw CreateExceptionHelperFunction("Ouch")     
    end if     
    return x 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [DoesNotReturnAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.doesnotreturnattribute) or this specific reason since .Net Core 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code (use Sub instead of Function)

```
Sub Foo(y As Integer)
    Dim x As Boolean
    If y > 10 Then
        x = 20
    Else
        ThrowHelperFunction("Ouch")
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: The function returns a value for a reason. Removing the function return value makes the error go away but also break the logic of the code!